# How to store current time in database

Tags: mysql

I want have a field in mysql where the Current time must be auto-generated, say when the record is inserted into it.

Please help me ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html):

> In a CREATE TABLE statement, the
>   first TIMESTAMP column can be declared
>   in any of the following ways:
>
> ```
> With both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE
> ```
>
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses, the column
>   has the current timestamp for its
>   default value, and is automatically
>   updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `TIMESTAMP` field, with the default set to `CURRENT TIMESTAMP`.

You can also use the `ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP` property and it will change whenever any field on the row is updated.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html